# Parameterize message in @available attribute

Tags: swift

After deprecating some functionality, I have a bunch of classes and functions with the  `@available` attribute like this:

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Deprecated. Some explanation comes here. See Help Page Name for more information.")
```

I don't like that I have duplicate text spread in multiple places. I would rather have the text defined somewhere and used as a parameter. Naive implementation, **which doesn't work**, would look like this:

```
struct AvailabilityConstants {
    static let explanationA = "Some explanation comes here. See Help Page Name for more information."
    static let explanationB = "Another explanation comes here. See Another Help Page Name for more information."
}
```

and then use them as

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: AvailabilityConstants.explanationA)
```

etc. But as I said that doesn't work, gives an error:

> Expected string literal in 'available' attribute

Indeed: strange to expect compile-time attribute to consume its compilation product.

Are there any other options? Is it even possible to parameterize attributes?

Comment: It's not possible, but this would make a good language feature request.